# Select multiple columns based on multiple conditions from single column

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by

I have a table in a database, which stores amounts, their respective ‘invoice dates’, and what year of the contract those invoice dates fall in.

There are customers on annual, bi-annual, quarterly and monthly contracts. So there can be multiple invoices for one yearly period - hence the column defining which year the invoices fall in.

It looks similar to this:

| ContractID | InvoiceNumber | InvoiceDate | Amount | YearIndex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2019 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 01/06/2019 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 01/01/2020 | 100 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 01/06/2020 | 100 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 01/03/2020 | 200 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 01/03/2020 | 200 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 01/03/2021 | 200 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 01/01/2020 | 300 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 01/04/2020 | 300 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 01/07/2020 | 300 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 01/10/2020 | 300 | 1 |

Ideally I want to run a query where I have something where I can see the sum of each contracts amounts, grouped by year index, e.g

| ContractID | Year1Amount | Year2Amount | Year3Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 200 | NULL |
| 2 | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| 3 | 1200 | NULL | NULL |

Is this possible from a single query? Or will this take joining multiple?

I’m working with Microsoft Access, in regards to available syntax.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just thought I'd add, Microsoft access doesn't support the CASE statement, only the IIF statements, however, IIF statements do not allow aggregate functions within them. So the answer ended up being the following for access:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT (ContractInvoiceInfo.ContractID), 
    Y1.Y1Amount, 
    Y2.Y2Amount, 
    Y3.Y3Amount, 
    Y4.Y4Amount, 
    Y5.Y5Amount

FROM 
    ContractInvoiceInfo INNER JOIN (
        (   
            SELECT ContractID, SUM(Amount) AS Y1Amount 
            FROM ContractInvoiceInfo 
            WHERE YearIndex = 1 
            GROUP BY ContractID
        )  AS Y1 LEFT JOIN (
            (   
                SELECT ContractID, SUM(Amount) AS Y2Amount 
                FROM ContractInvoiceInfo 
                WHERE YearIndex = 2 
                GROUP BY ContractID
            )  AS Y2 LEFT JOIN (
                (
                    SELECT ContractID, SUM(Amount) AS Y3Amount 
                    FROM ContractInvoiceInfo 
                    WHERE YearIndex = 3 
                    GROUP BY ContractID
                )  AS Y3 LEFT JOIN (
                    (
                        SELECT ContractID, SUM(Amount) AS Y4Amount 
                        FROM ContractInvoiceInfo 
                        WHERE YearIndex = 4 
                        GROUP BY ContractID
                    )  AS Y4 LEFT JOIN (
                            SELECT ContractID, SUM(Amount) AS Y5Amount 
                            FROM ContractInvoiceInfo 
                            WHERE YearIndex = 5 
                            GROUP BY ContractID
                            )  AS Y5 
                        ON Y5.ContractID = Y4.ContractID)
                    ON Y4.ContractID = Y3.ContractID)
                ON Y3.ContractID = Y2.ContractID)
            ON Y2.ContractID = Y1.ContractID)
        ON Y1.ContractID = ContractInvoiceInfo.ContractID

ORDER BY 
ContractInvoiceInfo.ContractID;
```

Comment: Crosstab query may be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

This is the general pattern. You can toggle the syntax for Access and Null vs. 0 based on what you need.

```
SELECT ContractID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YearIndex = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Year1Amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YearIndex = 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Year2Amount,
       ...
       SUM(CASE WHEN YearIndex = N THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS YearNAmount
  FROM SOME_TABLE
 GROUP
    BY ContactID
```

Comment: Thanks so much, totally forgot about Case.

Answer (score 1):

a database does not want to give you sums in side-by-side presentation...and you'll create much complexity to achieve that

what is readily available is:

groupID    groupYear    sumAmount

specifically using Access one uses a common feature called an aggregate query for which you'll find tutorials online